CORS ERROR - I cant POST from a Local Website to my Lambda AWS REST API
I am developing a IoT project in which i use an ESP32 to connect to the AWS MQTT Broker, i get some readings (is a smart parking) and generate some simple DynamoDB tables, I want to deploy an API to get some CRUD Operations over my Users Table.
This is the Lambda Code for it.
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    try:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
        table = dynamodb.Table('Users')

        # Ensure required fields are present
        if 'ID' not in event or 'name' not in event or 'credits' not in event:
            return {
                'statusCode': 400,
                'body': json.dumps('Missing required fields')
            }

        item = {
            'ID': event['ID'],
            'name': event['name'],
            'credits': int(event['credits']),
            'last_in': event.get('last_in', ''),
            'last_out': event.get('last_out', ''),
            'is_in': event.get('is_in', False)
        }

        table.put_item(Item=item)
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-store',
                'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
            },
            'body': json.dumps('User created successfully')
        }
    except Exception as e:
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,
            'body': json.dumps(f'Error: {str(e)}')
        }

And then i created a POST Method with CORS Activated METHODS
POST METHOD
Whenever i try to send some data from a localhost webpage i get a CORS ERROR
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create User</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h2>Create User</h2>
        <form id="createForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="createID">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="createID" placeholder="Enter user ID" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="createName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="createName" placeholder="Enter name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="createCredits">Credits</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="createCredits" placeholder="Enter credits" required>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        const apiUrl = 'myurl';

        document.getElementById('createForm').onsubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const id = document.getElementById('createID').value;
            const name = document.getElementById('createName').value;
            const credits = document.getElementById('createCredits').value;

            await fetch(`${apiUrl}/users`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ ID: id, name, credits: parseInt(credits) })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => alert(data.body))
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        };
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


Thats the HTML
My error states
Ensure CORS response header values are valid
A cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) request was blocked because of invalid or missing response headers of the request or the associated preflight request .
To fix this issue, ensure the response to the CORS request and/or the associated preflight request are not missing headers and use valid header values.
Note that if an opaque response is sufficient, the request's mode can be set to no-cors to fetch the resource with CORS disabled; that way CORS headers are not required but the response content is inaccessible (opaque).
1 request
Request Status  Preflight Request (if problematic)  Header  Problem Invalid Value (if available)
users  blocked     Access-Control-Allow-Origin Missing Header
I tried setting up the Headers thingy in both the Lambda Code and the User Route (CORS ACTIVATED)
But still get the same error
